# Ошибка при запуске C# в VS code

Tags: c#

Переустановил VS code и при запуске программы в терминале выдает такую ошибку:

scriptcs : Имя "scriptcs" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1
+scriptcs "c:\Project\OOP\OOP10.1\OOP10.1.cs"+ ~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound : (scriptcs:String) [], CommandNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Что делать?

Comment: Не лучшее вы средство взяли для обучения. Советую поставить полноценную IDE, которая будет вам все подсказывать, рассказывать, и т.д. Касательно ошибки - для запуска проекта, нужно установить специальное расширение (поиск по C#), а также настроить файл `launch.json` (или что-то такое), в котором будет прописано как, с какими аргументами, через что, будет запущен проект. Обычно Code предлагает сделать такой файл автоматически, при открытии проекта. Так что смотрите, есть расширение? А файл запуска? А в нем пути верные? А dotnet установлен? Команда `dotnet` работает?

Comment: Вот кстати [документация](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio-code?pivots=dotnet-7-0), в которой пункт 7 и рассказывает про запуск. Также посмотрите раздел "Отладка приложения".

Comment: @EvgeniyZ запускаю программу как раз через команду в терминале dotnet run. Стоит вроде как обычное расширение Code Runner (18 млн скачиваний). 
Сейчас посмотрю документацию

Comment: А должны запускать через F5, или кнопка пуск (зеленая такая) в интерфейсе. И расширение не то...

Comment: Смотрите, вот я создал простой проект консольный, я открываю эту папку в VS Code. В окне расширений я устанавливаю расширение, которое так и зовется `C#`. Перехожу во вкладку "Отладка" и вижу там [это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKTw7.png), жму там "Generate C# ...", либо "показать все автоматические ..." и выбираю создать, .NET. Как только я это сделаю, у меня в папке с проектом появится новая папка, под названием `.vscode`, в которой будет 2 `.json` файла. Имея это, я просто теперь жму `F5`, все, проект соберется [и запустится](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1rmA.png), без всяких команд в консоль

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос. Надо в файле настроек settings.json в строке "csharp" поменять значение на "cd $dir; dotnet run $fileName". Если не понятно, то вот видео https://youtu.be/CO4BGZOuUkM?t=435 с таймкодом. Тут человек все обьясняет.

Comment: А почему вы не пользуетесь инструментами IDE, которую используете? С таким же успехом можно открыть папку и написать там в адресной строке `dotnet run`, почему не настроить отладку, как я вам и сказал ранее? Зачем эти костыли и сторонние решения?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Пользуюсь, просто когда получил ошибку, пробовал и так, и так.